# Using .insert with Ruby Arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a function that is parsing an array of numbers into a string in correct phone number format.  Is there any way to condense this so that I only have to call .insert once?

```
createPhoneNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]) returns "(123) 456-7890")

def createPhoneNumber(numbers)
  numbers.insert(6, "-")
  numbers.insert(0, "(")
  numbers.insert(4, ")")
  numbers.insert(5, " ")
  numbers.join
end
```

Comment: This is something that'll break if you have international users, as phone number lengths and formats vary around the world. Also, method names are not camelCase, they're snake_case in Ruby so use `create_phone_number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def createPhoneNumber(numbers)
  "(#{numbers[0..2].join}) #{numbers[3..5].join}-#{numbers[6..9].join}"
end
```

There is no way I can think of where you would use `insert`, and use it only once.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind passing in a 10-character string instead, you can do

```
def createPhoneNumber( p )
    '(%s) %s-%s' % [p[0,3],p[3,3],p[6,4]]    
end
```

Example:

```
createPhoneNumber('1234567890') # => "(123) 456-7890"
```

Comment: Using a string is the right way to start. We see them in the "(xxx) xxx-xxxx" format in the US often, but elsewhere they'll vary. Even assuming they're ten digits is dangerous so the OP is painting their app into a US-centric corner.